# Spring STS - Dynamic java web app is not recognizing a roo project entities

Tags: java, spring-roo

I'm working with Spring STS tool in order to generate a Roo project containing the persistence layer only, not web mvc and stuff.
Then I created a new Maven Project with Dynamic Web Facet in order to have a web application running/using that Roo persistence project.
The error is that in STS the Roo entities are not being recognized by the other project, as you can notice in the screenshot at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5587634/Spring_STS_Roo_Error.png .

However when I run the web application via console by mvn run:jetty it works fine. 
I would like to know what I am missing in STS since I can't see what methods the Roo entities contains when I press ctrl+space.

Thank you

Comment: It seems you have combined a number of questions to just one, please try to ask each of them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely your Aspects from Roo that are complaining.  Its hard to tell, since I can't see what the actual errors are.  Select the offending project/items in the Package Explorer, then look at the Problems tab (usually below...open it if you can't find it).  The start clearing the errors.

Comment: Hi CodeChimp, yes, something related to that. Actually I need to know how to allow my Roo project to be used as a maven dependency in another projects. Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, you just add it as a dependency.  You can look in your local Maven repo (<your_user_dir>/.m2/repository), or just look at your pom.xml, and add that to your other project's POM.  I am not sure how much millage you will get, as the project will be a WAR most likely, but it should work that way.

Comment: Ok Guy, thanks a lot for your help. I've cleaned up my .m2 repository, so it has downloaded all the needed dependencies. Then I performed a mvn install in my Roo project. Now everything is working fine.